# How to label these points on the scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel("path to the file")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(7,3)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Player', 'Pos', 'Age'])
df.plot.scatter(x='Age',
                      y='Pos',
                      c='DarkBlue', xticks=([15,20,25,30,35,40]))
plt.show()
```

[Got the plot but not able to label these points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaiUC.png)

Comment: Do you want to label every single one of these points, or just specific ones?

Comment: @ChaddRobertson every point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you'd like to label each point, you can loop over each coordinate plotted, assigning it a label using `plt.text()` at the plotted point's position, like so:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

y_points = [i for i in range(0, 20)]
x_points = [(i*3) for i in y_points]

offset = 5

plt.figure()
plt.grid(True)
plt.scatter(x_points, y_points)

for i in range(0, len(x_points)):
    plt.text(x_points[i] - offset, y_points[i], f'{x_points[i]}')
    
plt.show()
```

In the above example it will give the following:

[image: Plot Example]

The offset is just to make the labels more readable so that they're not right on top of the scattered points.

Obviously we don't have access to your spreadsheet, but the same basic concept would apply.

**EDIT**

For non numerical values, you can simply define the string as the coordinate. This can be done like so:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

y_strings = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
x_values = [i for i, string in enumerate(y_strings)]

# Plot coordinates:

plt.scatter(x_values, y_strings)

for i, string in enumerate(y_strings):
    plt.text(x_values[i], string, f'{x_values[i]}:{string}')

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Which will provide the following output:

[image]

Comment: I am not able to do this as my y axis is a string, and x axis are integers. And the labels are strings themselves. Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Yeah, so I figured that based off of your axis. That's a fairly simple fix - just create a list of numerical values of the same length as your 'pos' column (can be done quite nicely using ```enumerate()``` as a replacement for ```range()``` in the above loop). Will add that onto my answer now for you.

Comment: Before I do, does **each** x value have a corresponding y string?

Comment: yeah, every x value has a corresponding y string

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work; posted another question regarding the same. Could you help me there?

Comment: What error are you getting? Because that should work perfectly fine if you have two arrays of equal dimensions, one comprised of strings, the other of integers. Sure will take a look.